# Custom data pass to pinterest in php

Tags: php, html, pinterest

I need pass custom data (image,name,price) to pinterest account.

How to do this one i have pinterest account and `APP_ID` & `APP_SECRET` so please help any one.

This is my HTML code :index.php

```
<?php require "boot.php"; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
        <h1>Login with Pinterest</h1>
        <!--p>Use this <a href="<?php echo $pinterest->auth->getLoginUrl('https://github.local/pinterest/demo/callback.php', array('read_public', 'write_public')); ?>">link to login</a> with your Pinterest account.</p-->


        <p>Use this <a href="<?php echo $pinterest->auth->getLoginUrl('https://localhost/pinterest/demo/callback.php', array('read_public', 'write_public')); ?>">link to login</a> with your Pinterest account.</p>


    </body>
</html>
```

This my php code:callback.php

```
<?php require "boot.php"; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $board = $pinterest->boards->create(array(
                "name"          => "Test from the pinterest",
                "description"   => "Test pinterest"
            ));
          $pinterest->pins->create(array(
                "board"         => "dirkgroenen/test-from-api",
                //"image_url"     => "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453974336165-b5c58464f1ed?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1000&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1925",
                //"image"         => "./test_image_from_unsplash.jpg",
                "image"         => "http://localhost/Pinterest/demo/testimage.jpg",
                "note"          => "test",
                //"link"          => "http://tld.com/072AE601DF7DB00445386F5C9CC46F74"
            ));

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my boot.php file:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require "../autoload.php";
    //$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
    //$dotenv->load();
     //$pinterest = new DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Pinterest(getenv("APP_ID"), getenv("APP_SECRET"));
     $pinterest = new DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Pinterest(getenv("4947671503463268619"), getenv("ce54e73e9f1f366748f3e616b48574c90f8557458bc1ed126bce70c9a6ae70cb"));

    print_r($pinterest);

    if (isset($_GET["code"])) {

       echo "comming";die;

        $token = $pinterest->auth->getOAuthToken($_GET["code"]);

        $pinterest->auth->setOAuthToken($token->access_token);

        setcookie("access_token", $token->access_token);

    } else if (isset($_GET["access_token"])) {

        $pinterest->auth->setOAuthToken($_GET["access_token"]);

    } else if (isset($_COOKIE["access_token"])) {

        $pinterest->auth->setOAuthToken($_COOKIE["access_token"]);

    } else {
        assert(false);
    }
?>
```

Comment: are you trying to create a save button? https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/save/

Comment: pass data to pinterest account

Comment: Hi  I have some array values like (image,name,price) i have to pass my pinterest account how?.

Comment: Hi I posted above my code please check with my code.

Comment: when ever i execute my code showing issue like :{"status": "failure", "message": "The authorization grant is invalid", "code": 283, "data": "Invalid Application ID"}

Comment: Which line of code is failing, exactly? From the error message, it seems like you didn't send the application ID, or didn't send it correctly.  Check the API documentation for how you are supposed to format the request. Either that or your application is not approved yet - in that case check your application's status (I guess maybe at https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/) or contact the Pinterest tehnical support to verify.

Comment: Hi  ADyson,, i have print this code  $pinterest = new DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Pinterest(getenv("4947671503463268619"), getenv("ce54e73e9f1f366748f3e616b48574c90f8557458bc1ed126bce70c9a6ae70cb"));

    print_r($pinterest);

Comment: print_r($pinterest) ....this out put is like :DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Pinterest Object ( [auth] => DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Auth\PinterestOAuth Object ( [client_id:DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Auth\PinterestOAuth:private] => [client_secret:DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Auth\PinterestOAuth:private] => [state:DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Auth\PinterestOAuth:private] => 0b890a8 [request:DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Auth\PinterestOAuth:private]   => Array ( ) )